# NSRange exception error to a nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am new to `iOS`.
I need to create an array of specific size and set all its elements to 0.
Than I need to add this array in a `NSUserDefaults`.

I did the following:

```
//declare and initialize the array
NSString *name=@"test";
int y=5;
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
for (int i=0; i< [testArray count];i++) [testArray addObject:0]; //initialize all elements with 0
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:testArray forKey:name];

//read the array form nsUserDefaults
  NSMutableArray *testArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:name] mutableCopy];
        [testArray replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]; //here i get the nsrangeexception index beyound bounds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
//declare and initialize the array
NSString *name=@"test";
int y=5;
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i< 100;i++) [testArray addObject:@"0"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:testArray forKey:name];

//read the array form nsUserDefaults
NSMutableArray *testArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:name]];
[testArray1 replaceObjectAtIndex:y withObject:@"1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for condition is wrong because there is no object in array so your count is 0

```
for (int i=0; i< 100; i++)
```

should be correct

Comment: this is the reason why is not working? do I have to set 100 in the for loop? WHy? isn t there an easier way to declare and initialize an array with a value for all the elements in a single line?

Comment: There is no way for it.

Comment: you need a specific size array and thats only way, if the size is dynamic then get it from service or something.

Comment: do u find this efficient? if i have a bunch of numbers between  1 - 100 and i need to keep track of which numbers I get and if there are no more numbers at input, display the numbers that were not written. is this solution the best one?

Comment: why not? its best if you know the array limit. even core c code written like that based on true known hard bounds

Comment: Thx @Retro. Yes, i do know the array limit. I just thought if this way is the best way to retain which values are written at the input and which not.